# PHP doctrine2, how to create a user with multiple roles

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance, doctrine-orm, extends

I am in the process of switching to the Doctrine ORM. In our application we have 2 roles a user can take on: customer and employee.

Previously we had a user's table, then a customer table and an employee table.

A user can be a customer, or an employee. A user can have multiple instances of employee. (They work for more than one company at the same time.) However, that user can also be a customer. So they should have an entry in the customer table as well.

Previously we had a relation like this:

```
users
- id

company_has_employee
- company_id
- employee_id

employees
- user_id
- other attributes

customers
- user_id
- other attributes
```

So as you can see there is only one entry in the user table (meaning the user only has one set of credentials for all of their roles.)

**How can I translate this functionality into doctrine?**

I have experimented with [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) in the Doctrine Docs but I feel as if this is more complicated than that.